# Problems using LEFT OUTER JOIN in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to show all data from Table_A and only where they match on the right side of the table which is Table_B.  I have 2 tables like this:
TABLE_A:

```
ID   FAC_ID    QUESTION      ACTION_ITEM
1      222       what?        do...
5      245       when?        make..
9      325        vcc          kjy
11     145        kne          juy
```

TABLE_B:

```
ID   FAC_ID    QUESTION      ACTION
5      245       when?        make..
```

When i run my sql statement, i want to show something like this:

```
ID   FAC_ID    QUESTION      ACTION_ITEM
1               what?         do...
5      245       when?        make..
9                vcc          kjy
11               kne          juy
```

but with my code, it is only showing one row of data where ID = 5.  Here is my code:

```
select A.ID, B.FAC_ID, A.QUESTION, A.ACTION_ITEM
 FROM TABLE_A A LEFT JOIN 
 TABLE_B B ON A.ID=B.ID
 WHERE FAC_ID = 245
```

Comment: Your where clause is telling it to show only 1 record. You also need to fix this because FAC_ID is in both tables and this query will not even work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query doesn't make any sense - your where clause will limit this to one row, based on your data, where the ID = 5.

I think you might need:

```
 SELECT A.ID, B.FAC_ID, A.QUESTION, A.ACTION_ITEM
 FROM TABLE_A A 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_B B 
   ON A.ID=B.ID
```

If you filter on ID = 5 (assuming FAC_ID = 5 is a typo in your question), you will only get a single row.

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing a column from table B in the WHERE clause.  Move that to the JOIN.

Actually, the example you posted won't even compile since FAC_ID is ambiguous.

Comment: sorry, i have upated the FAC_ID

Answer (score 0):

The where is turning it into and inner join

```
select A.ID, B.FAC_ID, A.QUESTION, A.ACTION_ITEM
 FROM TABLE_A A 
 LEFT JOIN TABLE_B B 
   ON A.ID = B.ID
  AND B.FAC_ID = 245
```

WHERE AND B.FAC_ID = 245 eliminates any B.FAC_ID is null and basically turns it into an innner join